# Generate randoop test case for whole package

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, package, randoop

How to generate randoop testcases for whole java package instead of mentioning all the classes name in classes.txt.

And if possible name those tests in accordingly to classNames for which it is being tested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`--testjar`](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#option:testjar) command-line options if there is a `.jar` file for the package.  This is the most common use.

Or, you can use a command like

```
find . -name '*.java' | sed 's/^\.\///' | sed 's/\.java$//' | sed 's:/:.:g'
```

to get a list of all the Java files in the package, to put in an argument to [`--classlist`](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html#option:classlist).  Note that if the package depends on other packages that you have excluded from generation, Randoop may not be able to test it thoroughly.